# How to change a JPanel property without affecting the original JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, background, pdf-generation, jpanel

I have a Java desktop application that at certain point shows up a JPanel with a GridBagLayout and others JPanels inside the grid. This JPanel is showed with a certain color. What I want is to export this JPanel to PDF (I'm using iText) with another color. 
No problem with the export (the PDF is generated with the JPanel in its original color) but I'm not sure of the right way to go for changing the JPanel color on the PDF.

My first approach was to set the backgroung color of the original JPanel for the color intended to go on the PDF. I have an utilitary class to generate my PDFs with a method that receives a JPanel and on this method, I made jPanel.setBackgroundColor. This works, but the problem (maybe obvious for most) is that it also changed the original JPanel showed on the application. I thought that invoking this method passing the JPanel would be Java pass-by-value. After some reading, I now understand that it is indeed a pass-by-value, but the value of the pointer to the object JPanel, and not really the object, thus changing it's property, also changes the original.

Another approach was to clone the original JPanel. But then noticed the JPanel is not Cloneable. Also thought of recreate the original JPanel over a new JPanel, but it's getting too complex.

So I'd like to have some opinions on which would be the right way to go.

Thank you very much in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: would it be acceptable to change the color while converting and then back to the original when done (might have a slight flicker in the desktop ui)? Or remove the panel while converting, maybe filling its area with a bufferedImage?

Answer (score 1):

One simple, but slightly different solution would be to wrap another panel around your panel before showing it on your GUI and before printing it.
If you use a different Panel for GUI and for printing, you can use two different background colors (and also different other settings).
Of course this is not a strict solution to the stated problem, but probably a rather good workaround.